# Instantiating a new arraylist then adding to the end of it

Tags: java, arraylist

```
public ArrayList<Person> people;
```

Is this how you would instantiate the people variable as a new empty ArrayList of Person objects?

```
ArrayList<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

And is this how you would add newMember to the end of the list?

```
public void addItem(Person newMember){
            people.add(newMember);

    }
```

Comment: What happens when you try it?  Does it work?

Comment: Yep, that will work just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### No

```
class Foo {
  public ArrayList<Person> people;

  Foo() {
    //this:
    ArrayList<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();
    //creates a new variable also called people!

    System.out.println(this.people);// prints "null"!
    System.out.println(people);//prints "bladiebla"
  }
  Foo() {
    people = new ArrayList<Person>();//this DOES work
  }
}
```

---

What it could(or should) look like:
`private`, `List` instead of `ArrayList` and `this.` so you never make that mistake again:

```
public class Foo {
  private List<Person> people;

  public Foo() {
    this.people = new ArrayList<Person>();
  }
  public void addItem(Person newMember) {
    people.add(newMember);
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `this` in front of `people`.

Comment: @SteveKuo But it's good to be consistent - 9 times out of 10, you will need `this` in constructors.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's correct. If you later wish to add an item to the middle of the list, use the add(int index, Object elem) method.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Answer (score 0):

In order to instantiate an empty `ArrayList` you have to explicitly define the number of elements in the constructor. An empty constructor allocates memory for 10 elements. According to documentation:

> public ArrayList()
>
> Constructs an empty list with an initial capacity of ten.

By default `add(item)` method of `ArrayList` add the element to the end of the list.